# linux show head of the first file from ls command

Tags: shell

I have a folder, e.g. named 'folder'. There are 50000 txt files under it, e.g, '00001.txt, 00002.txt, etc'.
Now I want to use one command line to show the head 10 lines in '00001.txt'. I have tried:
`ls folder | head -1`
which will show the filename of the first:
`00001.txt`
But I want to show the contents of `folder/00001.txt`
So, how do I do something like `os.path.join(folder, xx)` and show its `head -10`?

Comment: Something like `ls folder | head -n10 | awk '{print "folder/"$1}'`?

Comment: @AmmarFaizi, sorry about the late reply. Based on the comments, I think I didn't express my question clearly. I actually want to print out the top 10 lines in the first file found under the directory `folder`. Not printing out the top 10 relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do this is **not to use `ls` at all**; see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and the corresponding [UNIX & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) question [Why not parse `ls` (and what to do instead?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

On a shell with arrays, you can glob into an array, and refer to items it contains by index.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- bash, NOT sh; sh does not support arrays

# make array files contain entries like folder/0001.txt, folder/0002.txt, etc
files=( folder/* )  # note: if no files found, it will be files=( "folder/*" )

# make sure the first item in that array exists; if it does't, that means
# the glob failed to expand because no files matching the string exist.
if [[ -e ${files[0]} || -L ${files[0]} ]]; then
  # file exists; pass the name to head
  head -n 10 <"${files[0]}"
else
  # file does not exist; spit out an error
  echo "No files found in folder/" >&2
fi
```

If you wanted more control, I'd probably use `find`. For example, to skip directories, the `-type f` predicate can be used (with `-maxdepth 1` to turn off recursion):

```
IFS= read -r -d '' file < <(find folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -z)
head -10 -- "$file"
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not replying immediately. I tried, both would work. However, in the second example, I tried to play with it. I understand the latter part of the first line's command starting from `(find folder`, it seems that the result will a one line string containing the relative paths of my files. But I don't understand the part before that. Could you elaborate it a little bit? Much appreciate.

Comment: Why two `<` chars? Assigning to variable `$file`? I tried to delete the space between these two `<`, but not working.

Comment: Also, It seems that you are assigning `read -r -d` etc, to the variable `IFS`, but when I tried to `echo $IFS`, I got a blank line printed. Don't know what this means.

Comment: The following seems to work, too.   ```read -r -d '' file < <(find folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -z)
head -10 -- "$file"```

Comment: @StayFoolish, that's not what the `IFS=` does. It clears the internal field separator for the duration of the read.

Comment: @StayFoolish, as for `< <(...)`, the first `<` has its normal meaning, and then `<(...)` is process substitution syntax. They're two separate constructs, not one construct with two `<`s.

Answer (score 0):

Although hard to understand what you are asking but I think something like this will work:

```
head -10 $(ls | head -1)
```

Basically, you get the file from `$(ls | head -1)` and then print the content.

Comment: `$(ls | head -1)` isn't guaranteed to work there. The file may contain spaces or newlines (yes, they're legal). Your current `IFS` may contain a character like `.` that's found in the filename, causing `folder/0001` and `txt` to be passed to `head` as two separate arguments. See [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Ok, I think this would work if I'm currently inside the `folder` folder. But actually I'm at one level up. My 00001.txt file is inside `folder` dir, so I can't head 10 00001.txt. Assuming not considering spaces or newlines stuff as mentioned by @CharlesDuffy, is there any solutions like you mentioned? I'm sorry for not replying swiftly.

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke the `ls` command as `ls "$PWD"/folder`, it will include the absolute path of the file in the output.